# C# method for finding Book in list

Tags: c#

I have to make a Library class that has a list of Books with a Title, Author, and ID#. I have to make methods to add books, find books by title, display all books, and remove books.

Is my addBook() method correct?

I have an error with my findBook() method saying to create a constructor in the Book class but there already is a constructor.

Also I really have no idea where to begin to remove a Book from the list... I have looked up solutions for removing items from a list but I don't really get how I would implement it in my program.

I don't understand a lot of things because my first college course CSE 1301 was terrible, and I am in 1302 having to learn basic things plus the more complex things.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{

    public class Library
    {
        public string name;
        public List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        public void addBook(string title, string author)
        {
            int bookQuantity;

            string btitle;
            string bauthor;

            bookQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int x = 0; x <= bookQuantity; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Title:");

                btitle = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Author:");
                bauthor = Console.ReadLine();

                books.Add(new Book(btitle, bauthor));

            }
        }


        public void findBook()
        {
            var obj = new Book(title, author);
            obj.ID = "xy";
            string id = obj.ID;

            Book result = books.Find(x => x.ID == "xy");
        }

        public void displayBooks()
        {
            foreach (Book b in books)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void removeBook()
        {

        }

        public Library()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int id;
        static int isbn;

        public string ID { get; set; }

        public void assignID()
        {
            id = isbn;
            isbn++;
        }

        public Book(string title, string author)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Title: " + title, "\nAuthor: " + author, "\nISBN: " + id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First thing to do: learn about .NET naming conventions. Next, lean about properties and avoid public fields. Next, ask a *single* question per post, make it very specific, and provide a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal...)

Comment: I have an exam now. and I really need help

Comment: I'm afraid your urgency doesn't in any way affect the fact that Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of high quality questions and answers, and currently this question doesn't meet that bar - it's too broad, for a start. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: you cant help me now? 
This is my last hope to pass exam

Comment: Not without you improving your question, no. If you've waited until the last minute to ask for help, so that you don't have enough time even to prepare a proper question, the quality of the site shouldn't suffer for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your "findBook" method, you are creating a new book object twice, and not returning anything.

You probably want something like this:

```
public Book findBook(string id)
{
    return books.Find(x => x.ID == id);
}
```

If we break this down:

"public" is an "[Access Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers)" and describes who can access your method.

"Book" is the class of object we are going to return from the method. As we are looking for a Book, it makes sense to return an instance of the Book class here.

"findBook" is the name of your method.

"(string id)" in the braces you state the variables the method takes as input. We state we need a "string" and give it the name "id".

Finally to call this method we can use the code:

```
Book myBook = findBook("xy");
```

Comment: I'm afraid we aren't here to do exams or homework for you. Please take what I've written and try to learn what is going on. If you have any further questions please ask.

Comment: i cant do it :(
low level of English. I do not know how you do what you have written in code

Answer (score 0):

```
public Book findBook(string title, string author)
{
    Book result = null;
    foreach(Book b in books)
    {
        if(b.title == title && b.author == author)
        {
            result = b;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

also might be useful, to check if a book already exists

```
public bool hasBook(string title, string author)
{
    return (findBook(title, author) != null);
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why but it will not start. Well if it was would be start

Comment: what do you mean by it will not start?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Library
    {
        public List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        public void addBook(string title, string author)
        {
            var bookQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            for (int x = 0; x <= bookQuantity; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Title:");
                var btitle = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter Author:");
                var bauthor = Console.ReadLine();

                books.Add(new Book() { title = btitle, author = bauthor, ID = x + 1, isbn = x + 1 });
            }
        }


        public void findBook()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter ID:");
            var id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Book result = books.FirstOrDefault((book => book.ID == id));
        }

        public void displayBooks()
        {
            foreach (Book b in books)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void removeBook()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter ID:");
            var id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var temp = books.FirstOrDefault(book => book.ID == id);
            if (temp != null)
                books.Remove(temp);
        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public int isbn { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Title: " + title, "\nAuthor: " + author, "\nISBN: " + ID);
        }
    }
```

will this fix all your functionalities